# how to check out the right project from maven when I have known the java class

Tags: java, maven

For example, I have known that I want to use the class as below:
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/shared/Receiver.java?r=8808

But I don't know which project should be involved in the pom.xml of my maven project.

And I usually meet similar issue.

Is there any way for me to check the right project when I have got the official doc to specific java class ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be thrash answer, but works good for me:
Copy package name to google (or other search engine) and add maven at the end. If it is in maven repo and it wasn't added there few moments ago it should find it.

In you're case it would be serch for "com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared maven".